# How to execute multiple events on click?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to click the button and execute this 2 expressions.

But i need to click it twice to execute both:

1.) data = true and 2.) name(data). Why it cant execute on click?

```
<button @click="data = true,name(data)">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AlexHunter it's probably best to extract this logic away to a handler function. Something like the below.

```
<button @click="handleClick">click me</button>

.....
// in your methods section
methods: {
  handleClick() {
    this.data = true
    this.name(data)
  }
}
```

if `data` is something you're accessing from within a `v-if` you can instead pass it in to the handler as below,

```
<button @click="handleClick(data)">click me</button>

.....
// in your methods section
methods: {
  handleClick(data) {
    // if data is false, return and don't call this.name()
    if (!this.data) return

    this.name(data)
  }
}
```

Without seeing more of your code I'm not sure what your exact use case is, though I feel you could perhaps simplify the above even more so.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a semicolon should execute both expressions on click.

```js
<button @click="data = true; name(data)">click me</button>
```

Comment: tried, i have to click twice

Comment: You should share more of your code. I don't know what `data` and `name` means in your handler.

Comment: data = true is attached to a v-if on a div, if click show div and pass data to the function

Comment: Where is your data and name declared?